# Failure to rename duplicate column names with dplyr rename() and rename_with()

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyselect

Given a tibble or data.frame that has duplicate column names, I want to use `dplyr::rename` or `dplyr::rename_with` to either:
(a) differentiate the duplicate names with a serial numeric suffix (`'a_1'`, `'a_2'`, etc) or
(b) rename each column entirely.

Have:

```r
library(tidyverse)

d <- tibble(a = 1:3, a = letters[1:3], .name_repair = "minimal")

d
# A tibble: 3 x 2
      a a    
  <int> <chr>
1     1 a    
2     2 b    
3     3 c
```

Want:

```r
tibble(a_1 = 1:3, a_2 = letters[1:3])

# A tibble: 3 x 2
    a_1 a_2           # or even just: x, y    
  <int> <chr>
1     1 a    
2     2 b    
3     3 c
```

It seems reasonable to expect that `rename`/`rename_with` could perform this operation, especially since `colnames(d) <- c("a_1", "a_2")` seems obvious and uncomplicated.

But I've gotten different errors and/or unexpected behavior with the three approaches I've tried so far:

**1. Using `rename()`, one column is renamed, the other is not:**

```r
d %>% rename(x = "a", y = "a")  

# A tibble: 3 x 2
        y a    
    <int> <chr>
  1     1 a    
  2     2 b    
  3     3 c
```

**2. Using `rename_with()`, in which I use a function to add a numeric suffix, I get this error:**

```r
d %>% rename_with(~paste(.x, 1:2, sep = "_"))

Error: Names must be unique.
x These names are duplicated:
  * "a" at locations 1 and 2.
```

Note that this use of `rename_with` works as expected when data has no duplicate column names:

```r
no_dupe <- tibble(a = 1:3, b = letters[1:3])
no_dupe %>% rename_with(~paste(.x, 1:2, sep = "_"))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
    a_1 b_2  
  <int> <chr>
1     1 a    
2     2 b    
3     3 c
```

**3. Using the older `rename_all()`, I get a different error:**

```r
d %>% rename_all(paste0, 1:2)

Error: Can't rename duplicate variables to `{name}`.
```

I found a discussion about handling duplicates with `rename` in [the `tidyselect` GitHub issues](https://github.com/r-lib/tidyselect/pull/116), but that was about what to do if a user *creates* duplicate column names with `rename()`, not what to do if they are trying to unduplicate.

Am I missing syntax, or is the `dplyr::rename` family just not set up to ingest duplicate colnames?

(I'd also like to better understand why `rename` only renames one column in the example above, but that's less functional and more just me being curious.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `rename` does not know about the previous changes done so it renames the same column twice. This works `d %>% rename(x = "a") %>% rename(y = "a")`

Comment: As far as why `rename_with` doesn't work with duplicate column names it is because of this line I think https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/master/R/rename.R#L70 . We are not allowed to pass our own `repair` argument and it is always `"check_unique"`

Comment: Good find, @RonakShah, thanks for digging that up.  It's `rename_with()` I mainly care about, as I was hoping to find a programmatic way to assign suffixes to a number of duplicate colnames.  Would you mind writing that up as an answer?  Good to know about `rename()` not having "memory, too.

Comment: Why not store all col names in a vector.  Make another vector having 1:n of equal length.  Concatenate both vectors and replace colnames with result vector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rename` does not know about the previous change in name done. For example,

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% rename(a = mpg, b = a)
```

> Error: Can't rename columns that don't exist.
> x Column `a` doesn't exist.

So this

```
d %>% rename(x = "a", y = "a")
```

renames the same `a` column twice, first with `x` and then with `y`. An alternative is to break the pipe and rename.

```
d %>% rename(x = "a") %>% rename(y = "a")  

# A tibble: 3 x 2
#      x y    
#  <int> <chr>
#1     1 a    
#2     2 b    
#3     3 c
```

`rename_with` does not allow to rename dataframe/tibbles with duplicate columns because of https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/master/R/rename.R#L70 . In such case I think your best bet is to use base R methods.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
new_names <- c('a_1', 'a_2')
names(d) <- make.unique(dput(names(d)))
d %>% 
  rename_with(~new_names)
  # rename_at(vars(names(d)), ~new_names)
```

Out:

```
    a_1 a_2  
  <int> <chr>
1     1 a    
2     2 b    
3     3 c
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have multiple columns with duplicate or even triplicate column names you can also try this method..

Fetch all column names in a vector named v using `colnames`.  thereafter, follow this method..

```
v <- c("a", "a", "b", "c", "c", "c", "d", "e")

df <- tibble(v)


df <- df %>% mutate(id = 1) %>% 
  group_by(v) %>% 
  summarise(id = cumsum(id)) %>% 
  mutate(v2 = paste(v,id, sep = "_")) %>%
  mutate(v2 = ifelse(id==1, v, v2))
```

Last replace column names with `df$v2`

```
> df$v2
[1] "a"   "a_2" "b"   "c"   "c_2" "c_3" "d"   "e"
```